# Number flower pots in an arrangement

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

It's a Google interview question. There's a list of "T" and "F" only. All denotes a position such that T means position is occupied by a flower pot and F means pot is not there, so you can put another pot at this position. Find the number of pots that can be placed in a given arrangement such that no two pots are adjacent to each other(they can be adjacent in the given arrangement). If a position at the beginning is unoccupied then a pot can be placed if second position is also unoccupied and if the last position is unoccupied than a pot can be placed if second last position is also unoccupied. For ex.

TFFFTFFTFFFFT - returns 2
FFTTFFFFFTTFF - returns 4

I tried solving it by looking at adjacent values for every position with value F. Increased the counter if both adjacent positions were F and set this position as T. I need a better solution or any other solution(if any).

Comment: If you want to get a software job, this is *really* the kind of thing you should be able to solve yourself.

Comment: They will have changed the interview questions, and you will need to demonstrate knowledge of the CS principles behind the problems, not just a solution. StackExchange is not a substitute for learning. Start here: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/index.html

Comment: @user2357112, The question is not about how to get a job.

Comment: I need a direction to solve this problem or a concept that I'm not aware of yet.

Comment: Sounds like a valid question for me

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem like this.  You need FFF to have one more pot, FFFFF for two pots, etc.  To handle the end cases, add an F at each end.

Because this is very similar to a 16-bit integer, the algorithm should use tricks like binary arithmetic operations.

Here is an implementation in Python that uses bit masking (`value & 1`), bit shifting (`value >>= 1`) and math (`(zeros - 1) / 2`) to count empty slots and calculate how many flower pots could fit.

```
#value = 0b1000100100001
value = 0b0011000001100
width = 13
print bin(value)

pots = 0        # number of flower pots possible
zeros = 1       # number of zero bits in a row, start with one leading zero
for i in range(width):
    if value & 1:       # bit is one, count the number of zeros
        if zeros > 0:
            pots += (zeros - 1) / 2 
        zeros = 0
    else:       # bit is zero, increment the number found
        zeros += 1
    value >>= 1         # shift the bits to the right
zeros += 1              # add one trailing zero
pots += (zeros - 1) / 2 
print pots, "flower pots"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with a modified Mergesort. Consider the flowerpots that can be placed in the singletons, then the flowerpots that can be placed in the doubleton merges of those singletons, up the tree to the full arrangement. It would complete in `O(n lg n)` for a list of n flowerpots.

There is certainly a way to do this with a modified Rod Cutting algorithm with complexity `O(n^2)`. The subproblem is whether or not an open "false set" exists in the substring being considered. The "closed false sets" already have some maximum value computed for them. So, when a new character is added, it either increases the amount of flowerpots that can be inserted, or "locks in" the maximum quantity of available flowerpots for the substring.

Also, you know that the maximum flowerpots that can be placed in a set of *n* open positions bound by closed positions is *n - 2* (else *n-1* if only bracketed on one side, i.e. the string begins or ends with a "false set". The base condition (the first position is open, or the first position is closed) can calculated upon reaching the second flowerpot.

So, we can build up to the total number of flowerpots that can be inserted into the *whole arrangement* in terms of the maximum number of flowerpots that can be inserted into smaller *subarrangements* that have been previously calculated. By storing our previous calculations in an array, we reduce the amount of time necessary to calculate the maximum for the next subarrangement to a single array lookup and some constant-time calculations. This is the essence of dynamic programming!

EDIT: I updated the answer to provide a description of the Dynamic Programming approach. Please consider working through the interactive textbook I mentioned in the comments! http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse what has to be done.

So first we probably need to visit and examine each place. That suggests loop of some sort. E.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myPlaces.Length; ++i)
```

When we are at a spot we have to check if it's occupied

```
if (place[i] == 'F')
```

but that's not enough to place the flower pot there. We have to check if the next and previous place is free

```
place[i-1]
place[i+1]
```

If all tree contain `F` you can put the flower pot there and move to next field

Now, we also have some exceptions from the rule. Beginning and end of the list. So you have to deal with them separately. E.g

```
if (i == 0)
{
    // only check current position and next position
}

if (i == myPlaces.Length - 1) // minus 1 because indexing usually starts from 0
{
    // only check current position and previous position
}
```

After that you can perform the checks mentioned previously.

Now let's think of the input data. Generally, it's a good habit not to modify the input data but make a copy and work on the copy. Also some data structures work better than the others for different tasks. Here you can use simple string to keep entry values. But I would say an array of chars would be a better option because then, when you find a place where you can put a flower pot you can actually replace the `F` with the `T` in an array. Then when you move to new spot your data structers knows that there is already a pot in the previous position so your algorithm won't put an adjacent one.
You would not be able to do that with string as strings are immutable and you would need to generate a new string each time.

Note that it's only a naive algorithm with a lot of scope for improvement and optimization. But my goal was rather to give some idea how to approach this kind of problems in general. I'll leave implementing of the details to you as an afternoon exercise before targeting a job at Google.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Isn't it similar to the approach that I mentioned at the end of the question. I need to handle corner conditions. I mean I scan every element in the list. For every element I check both of adjacents and increment counter accordingly. I'll have corner conditions at index 0 and list.size-1 and handle them separately.

Comment: Sorry for long reply. Hoped someone reading your question can benefit from more thorough explanation. As to corner cases you can do it explicitly so check if it's 0 index. If so check next position and current position only. If it's last - check previous and current. And then, if it's neither of the cases, perform further checks - this way you will avoid index out of range exception.Also separately check if the length of total isn't just 1. Other approach would be as suggested by Brent Washburne. Only then remember to start iterating from 1 and end on Length - 1 but no need for edge cases then

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really simple, check the previous and current value of the position and mark the position as plantable (or puttable) and increment the count. Read the next value, if it is already is planted, (backtrack and) change the previous value and decrement the count. The complexity is O(n). What we really want to check is the occurrence of 1001. Following is the implementation of the algorithm in Java.

```
public boolean canPlaceFlowers(List<Boolean> flowerbed, int numberToPlace) {

    Boolean previous = false;
    boolean puttable = false;
    boolean prevChanged = false;
    int planted = 0;
    for (Boolean current : flowerbed) {
        if (previous == false && current == false) {
            puttable = true;
        }

        if (prevChanged == true && current == true) {
            planted--;
        }

        if (puttable) {
            previous = true;
            prevChanged = true;
            planted++;
            puttable = false;
        } else {
            previous = current;
            prevChanged = false;
        }
    }

    if (planted >= numberToPlace) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private static void canPlaceOneFlower(List<Boolean> flowerbed, FlowerBed fb) {
    boolean result;
    result = fb.canPlaceFlowers(flowerbed, 1);
    System.out.println("Can place 1 flower");
    if (result) {
        System.out.println("-->Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("-->No");
    }
}

private static void canPlaceTwoFlowers(List<Boolean> flowerbed, FlowerBed fb) {
    boolean result;
    result = fb.canPlaceFlowers(flowerbed, 2);
    System.out.println("Can place 2 flowers");
    if (result) {
        System.out.println("-->Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("-->No");
    }
}

private static void canPlaceThreeFlowers(List<Boolean> flowerbed, FlowerBed fb) {
    boolean result;
    result = fb.canPlaceFlowers(flowerbed, 3);
    System.out.println("Can place 3 flowers");
    if (result) {
        System.out.println("-->Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("-->No");
    }
}

private static void canPlaceFourFlowers(List<Boolean> flowerbed, FlowerBed fb) {
    boolean result;
    result = fb.canPlaceFlowers(flowerbed, 4);
    System.out.println("Can place 4 flowers");
    if (result) {
        System.out.println("-->Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("-->No");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Boolean> flowerbed = makeBed(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    FlowerBed fb = new FlowerBed();

    canPlaceFourFlowers(flowerbed, fb);
    canPlaceThreeFlowers(flowerbed, fb);
    flowerbed = makeBed(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 });
    canPlaceFourFlowers(flowerbed, fb);
    canPlaceThreeFlowers(flowerbed, fb);
    canPlaceTwoFlowers(flowerbed, fb);

    flowerbed = makeBed(new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 });

    canPlaceFourFlowers(flowerbed, fb);
    canPlaceThreeFlowers(flowerbed, fb);
    canPlaceTwoFlowers(flowerbed, fb);
    canPlaceOneFlower(flowerbed, fb);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My solution using dynamic programming.

`ar` is array in the form of ['F','T','F'].

```
import numpy as np
def pot(ar):
    s = len(ar)
    rt = np.zeros((s,s))
    for k in range(0,s):
        for i in range(s-k):
            for j in range(i,i+k+1):
                left = 0
                right = 0
                if ar[j] != 'F':
                    continue
                if j-1 >= i and ar[j-1] == 'T':
                    continue
                else:
                    left = 0
                if j+1 <= i+k and ar[j+1] == 'T':
                    continue
                else:
                    right = 0
                if j-2 >= i:
                    left = rt[i][j-2]
                if j+2 <= i+k:
                    right = rt[j+2][i+k]
                rt[i][i+k] = max(rt[i][i+k], left+right+1)
    return rt[0][len(ar)-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution written in C#

```
    private static int CheckAvailableSlots(string str)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        char[] chrs = str.ToCharArray();

        if (chrs.FirstOrDefault().Equals('F'))
            if (chrs.Length == 1)
                counter++;
            else if (chrs.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Equals('F'))
                counter++;

        if (chrs.LastOrDefault().Equals('F') && chrs.Reverse().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Equals('F'))
            counter++;

        for (int i = 1; i < chrs.Length - 2; i++)
        {
            if (chrs[i - 1].Equals('T'))
                continue;
            else if (chrs[i].Equals('F') && chrs[i + 1].Equals('F'))
            {
                chrs[i] = 'T';
                counter++;
                i++;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
// 1='T'
// 0='F'
int[] flowerbed = new int[] {1,0,0,0,0,1};
```

```java
public boolean canPlaceFlowers(int[] flowerbed, int n) {
    int tg = 0;
    for (int i = 0, g = 1; i < flowerbed.length && tg < n; i++) {
        g += flowerbed[i] == 0 ? flowerbed.length - 1 == i ? 2 : 1 : 0;

        if (flowerbed[i] == 1 || i == flowerbed.length - 1) {
            tg += g / 2 - (g % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0);
            g = 0;
        }
    }
    return tg >= n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers (unless they alter the array or traverse and a copy) dont consider the situation where the first 3 (or last 3) pots are empty. These solutions will incorrectly determine that FFFT will contain 2 spaces, rather than just one. We therefore need to start at the third element (rather than then second) and end at index length - 3 (rather than length - 2). Also, while looping through the array, if an eligible index is found, the index just be incremented by 2, otherwise TTFFFFT would give 2 available plots instead of one. This is true unless you alter the array while looping or use a copy of the array and alter it.

Edit: this holds true unless the question is how many spaces are available for planting, rather than how many total plants can be added

Answer (score 0):

**C++ solution**

```cpp
int canPlaceFlowers(vector < char > & fb) {
  int count {};

  auto pot = [ & fb, & count](int index) -> void {
    fb[index] = 'T';
    ++count;
  };

  auto is_free = [ & fb](int index) -> bool {
    return fb[index] == 'F';
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < fb.size(); ++i) {
    if (!is_free(i)) {
      continue;
    }

    bool is_prev_valid = i > 0 ? true : false;
    bool is_next_valid = i < fb.size() - 1 ? true : false;
    bool is_prev_free = is_prev_valid && is_free(i - 1);
    bool is_next_free = is_next_valid && is_free(i + 1);

    //first pot location but not alone
    if (!is_prev_valid && is_next_valid) {
      if (is_next_free) {
        pot(i);
      }
    }
    //not first/last pot location
    else if (is_prev_valid && is_next_valid) {
      if (is_prev_free && is_next_free) {
        pot(i);
      }
    }
    //last pot location but not alone
    else if (is_prev_valid && !is_next_valid) {
      if (is_prev_free) {
        pot(i);
      }
    }
    //only pot location
    else if (!is_prev_valid && !is_next_valid) {
      pot(i);
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should add an explanatory text to the answer instead of just writing 'solution'.